# Scala 2.11.8, OS:Windows 7, Java: JDK1.8

Tags: scala

I am creating a Companion Objects, How do i traverse these objects?, i have written but not working, error thrown

Please help here

```
scala> :paste
object Network {
  class Member(val name: String) {
    var strName = name
    val contacts = new collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Member]
    println(" name -->" + strName)
  }
}

class Network {
  private val members = new collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Network.Member]
  def join(name: String) = {
    val m = new Network.Member(name)
    members += m
    m
  }
}

val chatter = new Network
val myFace = new Network
val fred = chatter.join("Fred")
val wilma = chatter.join("Wilma")
fred.contacts += wilma // OK
val barney = myFace.join("Barney") // Has type myFace.Member
fred.contacts += barney // allowed
```

How do i traverse these objects?, i have written but not working, error thrown

```
for (a<- fred.contacts){
  var Network.Member m = a
  println("m -->" + m.strName)
  //println("m -->" + a)
}
```

Comment: 1. You need to properly format your code if you expect anyone to read it. 2. You didn't even say what the error was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of `m` variable is not correct.

```
var m:Network.Member = a
```

That's the correct way to declare a variable in Scala. Or you can just ignore the type and let Scala interpret it.

```
var m = a
```

Comment: Yes you are right, Thanks, I am learning from Java to Scala so hurdles always exists, because syntax forgot :)       This is fixed